# Is there a way to assign a friendly name to Microsoft Azure MSDN Subscriptions?

Tags: azure, msdn

I have three (3) active MSDN Subscriptions on my account. Two expire in 2017, and the third expires in 2018.

The title says it all, is there a way to give a "friendly" name to these subscriptions? (i.e. "Work", "Personal", "Misc"). I modified the image to remove the GUIDs, but I really don't want to have to memorize the GUIDs to know which subscription I am creating new resources under when I do things such as creating VM, etc. I also don't want to get billed for certain services to the wrong subscription.

Oh, and the MSDN website isn't any more useful. It allows me to Remove a subscription or transfer the subscription to another account, but not to give an alias or friendly name to a subscription.

[image: MSDN Subscriptions]

Comment: Yes there is, it is somewhere in the account section of the old portal, I'm not in front of a comp right now, but when I am I'll write a proper answer, if you've not found it by then

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an azure subscription support question, not a programming question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: if this needs to be moved to another stack, by all means suggest a different stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Go to account.windowsazure.com, select your subscription, then edit subscription details.